# Ubuntu 12.04 - Integrated Webcam not found with lsusb but it shows up in usb-devices?

Tags: 12.04, skype, webcam, alienware

This is an Alienware Area-51 m15x laptop, pre-2009 so not a Dell product.  The integrated webcam worked under Ubuntu 10.x and I actually had it working briefly and could see my face in guvcview after trying a lot of different suggestions but it stopped working after powering down and I can't figure out what made it work.

When I run lsusb, it doesn't currently show up as installed, but usb-devices has it showing up just fine:

```
    T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
    D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
    P:  Vendor=152d ProdID=0770 Rev=01.00
    S:  Manufacturer=OmniVision Technologies, Inc. -2640-08.01.03.2
    S:  Product=Alienware Integrated Webcam
    C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
    I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
    I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
```

guvcview gives this error in the terminal:

```
    Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
    Cannot connect to server socket
    jack server is not running or cannot be started
    video device: /dev/video0 
    unable to detect video devices on your system (0)
    ERROR opening V4L interface: No such file or directory
    Init video returned -1
```

, returns "unable to open device" in a window and this error before closing out:

```
    VIDIOC_REQBUFS - Failed to delete buffers: Inappropriate ioctl for device (errno 25)
```

When I run ls /dev | grep -i video there is no output, so there is neither a video0 or video1 file there.  I have seen in other questions people have made that there is a way to create these but I have been unable to find the method I saw earlier - it could be that was what allowed the webcam to work briefly but I don't understand why it would have stopped working after powering down.

dmesg returns this error:

```
    [ 7295.860073] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
    [ 7295.912921] sdhci-pci 0000:0a:09.0: Will use DMA mode even though HW doesn't fully claim to support it.
    [ 7295.997221] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0770
    [ 7295.997233] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    [ 7295.997241] usb 1-2: Product: Alienware Integrated Webcam
    [ 7295.997248] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: OmniVision Technologies, Inc. -2640-08.01.03.2
    [ 7295.998679] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Alienware Integrated Webcam (152d:0770)
    [ 7295.999078] uvcvideo: UVC non compliance - GET_DEF(PROBE) not supported. Enabling workaround.
    [ 7295.999456] uvcvideo: Failed to query (129) UVC probe control : -32 (exp. 26).
    [ 7295.999463] uvcvideo: Failed to initialize the device (-5).
```

and gstreamer-properties has no devices listed for video input, likewise Skype and Cheese both report the webcam undetected.   Again, it did work briefly but then it stopped so it works in theory, any help would be greatly appreciated as I've spent quite a bit of time trying to figure this out and it seems like there are a lot of half-fixes out there for similar issues so I wanted to document this fully as it's figured out, thanks for reading.

Comment: Maybe to make answering this a little simpler, can anyone tell me how to manually force video0 or video1 to show up in the /dev directory?  I think this is what had it working briefly but I can't locate site where I saw how to do it.